# Какие есть библиотеки для целочисленной оптимизации python?

Tags: python, оптимизация

Есть достаточно большая система линейных уравнений A*x=B. С большой вероятностью система несовместна. Требуется найти такой вектор x0 над полем целых чисел, чтобы выражение sum((A*x0-B)**2) было минимально. Какие есть библиотеки python, для подобных целей? Было бы идеально проводить расчет на ГПУ, если такие решения существуют.

Comment: https://www.cvxpy.org/

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо, вроде то, что нужно! Возникли еще вопросы, может вы и на них ответ знаете? Я так понял, мне следует использовать решатель SCIP. Нахождение оптимального решения может идти слишком долго и мне нужна возможность каждую минуту смотреть на текущее качество и, если меня оно устаивает, остановить программу. Я разобрался как поставить лимит на время решения в нем, но не понимаю возможно ли продолжить текущее решение после остановки по лимиту времени?

Comment: Я ни разу не специалист. Посмотрите сюда https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt и сюда https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/FAQ.php#howtopasssolution